# Массив данных из фигурных скобок в строке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не могу получить массив из строки, если перед скобками есть символы

```
"string1", "string2"
```

```php
$string = "
    iojefu { string1 }
    asdjhu { string2 }
";

$array = preg_split('/\{|\}(.*)?/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Непонятно что именно вы хотите получить. `"string1", "string2"` - это желаемый результат? тогда для этого `preg_match_all` больше подходит, а не `preg_split`.

Comment: @hindmost, Желаемый результат `"string1", "string2"`. А `preg_match_all` в этом выражении выводит массив из фигурных скобок `"{", "}", "{", "}"`

Comment: `/{\s(.+)\s}/` даст вам с помощью `preg_match_all` желаемый результат в `matches[1]`

Comment: @teran, получается массив с тремя пустыми

Comment: А в `string1` и `string2` могут быть любые символы, да? Или только буквы, цифры и _? [Посмотрите, как ещё можно получить эти значения](https://ideone.com/ySYhVI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`preg_match`** ищет совпадения по шаблону, а на выходе получается многомерный массив, что было лишним в моём случае

**`preg_split`** же исключает лишнее, в результате получается чистый одномерный массив

---

Добавил в выражение исключение пробелов и табуляции `\s` и исключение до скобок `.*?`

```
$array = preg_split('/.*?\{|\}|\s/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

```php
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(7) "string1"
    [1]=> string(7) "string2"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ищем регуляркой строки внутри фигурных скобок, игнорируя опциональные пробелы вокруг строки:

```
$string = "
    iojefu { string1 }
    asdjhu { string2 }
";
preg_match_all('/\{\s*(?P<str>[^}]+?)\s*\}/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches['str']);
/*
array(2) {
  [0] => string(7) "string1"
  [1] => string(7) "string2"
}
*/
```

Конструкция `(?P<name>pattern)` (с 5.2.2 допустимы два новых варианта:  `(?<name>pattern)` и `(?'name'pattern)`) даёт имя маски и результат будет доступен по одноимённому ключу массива выходных данных; за деталями можно сходить сюда http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php

Сам шаблон поиска `[^}]+?` выбирает между скобками всё, что не является закрывающей фигурной скобкой. Для игнорирования конечного пробела использован ленивый квантификатор `+?`, но его можно заменить на жадный `+`, если добавить пробельные символы в список исключаемых в поиске - `[^}\s]+`.

Comment: распишите подробнее про именование подмасок. можно и просто `?<str>` без `P` начиная с 5.2.2

Comment: Похоже на то, что нужно, но опять же получается много данных на выходе, это 3 подобных массива 0 и результат с 1 и str

Comment: Вас не должно беспокоить "много выходных данных". Если конечно там строка не на пару Гб :)

Comment: Конструкция `(?P<name>` даёт имя маски и результат будет доступен по одноимённому ключу массива выходных данных, за деталями можно сходить сюда http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php

Comment: @Lexx918 дак в текст вопроса и напишите, в комменты то что писать. Ответ таки не из одного кода должен состоять, а и из объяснения какого-то. Вернее этим хороший ответ отличается от плохого. Среди остальных ваш ответ выдяеляет использование подмасок, за что получили от меня плюс. просто доработайте текст ответа, и будет гораздо лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Если не учитывать случаи вложенных скобок `{{}}`, то будет работать это:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/\{\s*([^}\s]*)\s*\}/', $string, $matches);
```

Результат будет в $matches[1]

Comment: пробелы с краев остаются

Comment: @teran Поправил

Comment: То же, что и у Lexx918, но без третьего массива

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли про квантификаторы. Выражение `\{|\}` ищет ровно один символ, а вам нужно как минимум 3: `{`, `}` и то что между ними (без пробелов), а оно насколько я понял может содержать все кроме фигурных скобок. Так что вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
/[{]\s*([^{}]+)\s*[}]/
```

Comment: С этим выражением у `preg_split` получается массив из `"iojefu"` и `"asdjhu"`. У `preg_match_all` многомерный массив, что не страшно, но на выходе данные со скобками, мне без них желательно

Comment: Используйте `preg_match_all`, а не `preg_split`. А на выходе берите массив подстрок